# remove child from parent in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

model

```
public class model
  {
    public int modelid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public List<childModel> childModel{ get; set; }
}
public class childModel
{

    public int childModelid { get; set; }
    public string childname { get; set; }
}
```

java script

```
@{
   var datam = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model);
 }
var helloWorldModel = {
        model: ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(datam)),
        dele: function (models) {
            helloWorldModel.model.remove(models);
        }
    }

 ko.applyBindings(helloWorldModel);
```

html

```
    <span data-bind="foreach:model">
      <span data-bind="text : name"></span>

       <span data-bind="foreach:childmodel">
          <input type="text" data-bind="value:childname" />
       </span>

    <input type="button" data-bind="click:$parent.dele" value="delete parent" />
  </span>
```

so i can remove model, but is there any way to remove childmodel whith this structure?
something like this:

```
        deleChildModel: function (Childmodels) {
            helloWorldModel.model.childModel.remove(Childmodels);
        }
```

i can add add modelid to ChildModel and then use

```
           deleChildModel: function (Childmodels) {
            helloWorldModel.model()[Childmodels.modelid].childModel.remove(Childmodels);
            }
```

but i am looking for something simpler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bind` to have the button pass the parent as well as the child to the deleteChild function. The first argument to `bind` provides the context (`this`) for when the resulting function is called.

```js
var models = [{
  name: 'One',
  childmodel: [{
    childname: "SubOne"
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Two',
  childmodel: [{
    childname: "SubTwo"
  }]
}];

var vm = (function() {
  var self = {
    model: ko.mapping.fromJS(models),
    dele: function(item) {
      self.model.remove(item);
    },
    deleteChild: function(child) {
      var parent = this;
      parent.childmodel.remove(child);
    }
  };
  return self;
}());

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>
<span data-bind="foreach:model">
      <span data-bind="text : name"></span>

<span data-bind="foreach:childmodel">
          <input type="text" data-bind="value:childname" />
          <button data-bind="click:$root.deleteChild.bind($parent)">Delete Child</button>
       </span>

<input type="button" data-bind="click:$parent.dele" value="delete parent" />
</span>
```